# WCF Service Impersonation

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Good Day Everyone...

Apparently, I'm not setting-up impersonation correctly for my WCF service.  I do NOT want to set security on a method-by-method basis (in the actual code-behind).  The service (at the moment) is open to be called by everyone on the intranet.

So my questions are…

Q: What web-config tags am I missing?

Q: What do I need to change in the web-config to make impersonation work?

**The Service Web.config Looks Like...**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <identity impersonate="true" userName="MyDomain\MyUser" password="MyPassword"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfFISH.DataServiceBehavior" name="wcfFISH.DataService">
                    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="wcfFISH.IFishData">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                </service>
            </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="wcfFISH.DataServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always want to impersonate the client, for all operations, then add the following to the `<behavior>` element, i.e. after the `<serviceMetadata>` element:

```
<serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
```

---

If you're trying to impersonate at the *application* level, then you normally can't do this in WCF, since WCF isn't really part of the ASP.NET pipeline.

The easiest workaround is just to **put the WCF application in its own Application Pool and set the process identity of the pool to the user you want to impersonate.**

The other way is turn on ASP.NET compatibility mode, adding this to `<system.servicemodel>`:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

You also sometimes need to decorate your service with:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
    RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

But keep in mind that this is going to limit your ability to take advantage of a lot of other newer WCF features like MSMQ or TCP bindings.  I prefer the segregated app pool approach.

Comment: I do NOT want to impersonate the client.  I want the service to connect to the database.  For some reason...it won't.  The LOGIN & PASSWORD are correct...but the service won't take-on the identity.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584198/authentication-service-using-wcf ?